# Cannot pass data with ajax to razor pages

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I am trying to send some data to razor page method, but the problem is that in method it takes always as `0`.

Heres the code:

Razor Page:

```
public IActionResult OnGetProducts(int page)
{
    var products = _productRepository.GetProducts();

    decimal pagesInDecimal = (products.Count() / 18);
    var totalPages = pagesInDecimal % 1 == 0 ? pagesInDecimal : pagesInDecimal + 1;

    products = products.Skip((page - 1) * 20).Take(20);

    return new JsonResult(new {
        totalPages = totalPages,
        products = products
    });
}
```

Ajax:

```js
getProducts(1);            
function getProducts(page) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/Products",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            page: page,
            handler: 'Products'
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        success: function (datas) {
            console.log(datas);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`page` is essentially a reserved name when using ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages. The problem you have is actually quite simple, yet very subtle:

When it sees a query-string parameter, the ASP.NET Core 2.0 Razor Pages framework interprets this as the name of the current Razor Page - You can see that if you change your `page` parameter to type `string`; it'll actually contain the name of the current page. In your case, because the type is an `int`, the model-binding process cannot bind a string (the name) to a number, so sets it to `0`.

One way to work around this issue is to use a different name. e.g.:

```
public IActionResult OnGetProducts(int pageNumber)
```

-and-

```
data: {
    pageNumber: page,
    handler: 'Products'
}
```

There's a fair bit of discussion *around* this issue on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6660), but it's not specific to your scenario. I suggest you either search for or raise a new issue that specifically talks about using a query-string parameter in a Razor Page.

As an unrelated side note, you don't need to set the `Content-Type` header in your `$.ajax` request - This is used when you are sending content, which you're not.