# Why does Url.Action() return a NULL for this action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC app. It's using attribute routing.
I'm trying to get the correct URL for `GetProperties` and I'd expect it to be something like "/objects?page=1" - pointing my browser to that URL works like charm, the `GetProperties` method gets passed the correct value for `page` but I have no luck with `Url.Action()`.

**Controller:**

```
[Route("objects")]
public class ObjectListController : Controller
```

**Action:**

```
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetProperties(int? page)
```

**CSHTML:**

```
// This works - it returns "/objects" but obviously without any query params.
@Url.Action("GetProperties", "ObjectList")

// This returns NULL 
@Url.Action("GetProperties", "ObjectList", new { page = 1 })
```

Why is it not generating the expected URL?

**EDIT**

Using `Url.RouteUrl("GetPropertiesRouteName", new { page = 1 })` instead of `Url.Action()` works when adding this to the action:

`[HttpGet("", Name = "GetPropertiesRouteName")]`

Comment: `page` is a reserved token, so I expect that is the cause of your issue here. To confirm, just rename it to e.g. `pageNumber` and see if it works with that.

Comment: @Anadi there is no default routing. It's just `UseMvc()` and then attribute routing in the controllers.

Comment: @KirkLarkin you were right. Renaming `page` to `pageNum`! How is this a reserved token and where is it documented? Make it an answer and you score :-)

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7876

Comment: It's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reserved-routing-names), although only briefly. `page` is used for Razor Pages. Here are a couple of related questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47848183/cannot-pass-data-with-ajax-to-razor-pages/47849329) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52780914/pagination-and-pages-conflict-asp-net-core-razor-pages-conflicts-with-mvc-cont/52781403) that I answered.